# Conditional access policy for accessing vm in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-policy

**Scenario**

An invited guest user should be able to connect to a vm via Bastion, but only, if the user resides in a certain country/location.

**What did we do so far**

- We've created a named location for a specific country
- That has been added as a condition to a conditional access policy
- We've included a user group in which the guest user has been assigned to
- For "Cloud apps or actions" we really don't know what to set there for our problem. Any constellation didn't help

The policy didn't work so far. We were able to connect from several countries which weren't specified.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called 'Microsoft Azure Management' that you can select here but note this will block the user from the Azure portal entirely and not just to Azure Bastion. There is no way to limit conditional access to just the Azure Bastion service at this time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditional-access-azure-management